If the start state of an NFA is also an accept state, what happens when the input does not have transition to another state?
I am having some trouble understanding Figure 1.36 in Sipser's book.  It deals with a simple NFA that accepts strings epsilon, a, baba, and baa. But rejects strings b, bb, and baa
But q_1 does not have any transition from input a. How can it be accepted? I was under the impression that if given an input that the current state doesn't have any way to go, it goes to a dead state
Also, on input epsilon, there is a transition to q_3, but the book says it accepts epsilon. Does this mean the automaton separates into two possible outcomes? That is, on epsilon input in q_1 the possible transitions are: stay in q_1 or move to q_3?
https://imgur.com/a/ameZ9If   state diagram of the NFA


But q_1 does not have any transition from input a. How can it be accepted?

This is because there is an $\epsilon$ transition from $q_1$ to $q_3$ so you can jump to $q_3$ without reading anything. And then, you can jump to $q_1$ (an accepting state) on reading 'a'.

I was under the impression that if given an input that the current state doesn't have any way to go, it goes to a dead state

While traversing an NFA, if you are at a state $q$ and have $l$ as the next letter of the string that you are traversing, then if there is no transition from $q$ on $l$, you simply stop (and/or continue on the other possibilities of states as it is an NFA). The introduction of dead state and making transitions to it comes when you have to actually convert an NFA to a DFA.

That is, on epsilon input in q_1 the possible transitions are: stay in q_1 or move to q_3?

Yes, $\epsilon$ is technically the empty string. So, if you have it as input, you can remain at the start state or jump to any state that has $\epsilon$-transition from the start state (in this example, $q_3$). $\epsilon$ is an accepted string here as there is at least one run of NFA (in this case just staying at the start state) that ends at an accept state after reading $\epsilon$.
Hope this helps!
-- SG

It does! Thank you :)
